# jQuery localScroll, one click handles two events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the plugin [localScroll](http://www.agendadelvolo.info), where you can see that one click on the menu is handling two separate scrollings: the boxes and the footer's content.

The problem is that it is creating trouble in the layout, like the footer's dislocated left alignment, or its being attached to the container.

Could anyone tell me what I should add in the code?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'x';
    $('#menu').localScroll({
        target:'body',
        offset: -225
    }); 
});
```

I tried to modify `$('#menu, #footer_top').localScroll` but it doesn't work.

Comment: what's the issue exactly? it's not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: I'm trying to have the footer's content scrollable as well, together with the main website's content... all triggered by the same click

Comment: not solved yet - please help

Comment: and what exactly is wrong with the current implementation? I see both the content and footer scrolling

Comment: you should work on improving your markup/CSS layout, almost everything in your page is positioned absolutely and with fixed dimensions/positioning, a couple tips: set `<html>` height to 100% and add overflow hidden to `<body>`, that kind of makes it work ok for me